# Adding GitHub project to Launchpad PPA Package

Tags: linux, debian, open-source, packaging, launchpad

I am trying to figure out how to add a GitHub project to my simple, working Launchpad PPA package. The GitHub project that I am try to add is https://github.com/compiz-reloaded/compiz-boxmenu. I couldn't find much help online and I'm hoping that someone can help point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: You can't.  Launchpad will _not_ follow external links (as I found with package code for free-but-external fonts).  You can however package what you have at GitHub and build it inside launchpad.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! So how do I go about packaging what I have at Github and building it inside launchpad? I guess that is where I am stuck.

Comment: That's a whole different question.

Comment: Ie 'how do I build a Debian package?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'debianize'  your package first. The debianization depends on the package type, and the manual for a package debianization is called [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/devel-manuals#policy).

This [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian) is also very useful. Once you have your package debianized, you should compile it using the source option (I usually do it using `dpkg-buildpackage -S`. Pass your key using `-k<Key>` also. The same one you uploaded to your launchpad account.

Once you built your source, you will find a file called package_version.changes. You basically upload it as described in your PPA information. The package will be compiled, and, if no errors are found, it will be available in the PPA. If you want to enable the build for other architectures, as IBM POWER (ppc64el) or ARM (aarch64) , you should opt in.